# Win Batch reading file - does not save input to other file

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

I want to read a .csv line by line, remove spaces, than echo the lines to another .csv as a "filtered" output. First my input:

```
test 
 test
    t e st  .
th isssss    a te st
```

Now my parsing script (updated):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
cls


del K:\Users\Ultron\test\test2.csv
echo CSRV>>K:\Users\Ultron\test\test2.csv


for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (K:\Users\Ultron\test\test.csv) do (
set "line=%%A" 
echo %line%
echo %line% >>K:\Users\Ultron\test\test2.csv
)


notepad K:\Users\Ultron\test\test2.csv
```

Now notepad opens and reveals the hopefully expected result:

```
CSRV
ECHO Turned Off (OFF).
ECHO ist ausgeschaltet (OFF).
ECHO ist ausgeschaltet (OFF).
ECHO ist ausgeschaltet (OFF).
```

If I turn on echo I can see, that the lines are properly read, however it does not print them to the file. If the echo is on, the file contains the same information, only that it says, "ECHO is turned on (ON)."

It does not save the actual variable.

Comment: For loops can only use 32 tokens. Your posted code terminates the for loop with a closing parentheses prior to writing the output to file, so only the last value is output. Additionally, When assigning input to variables, Use the doublequote method `Set "varname=value"`

Comment: This does not improofe the result: "tokens=1-10*" only outputs: "th"

Comment: And what is the matter with Set "varname=value". I never used this method and actually wrote insanely complex batch scripts. Yet I cannot archive such a simple thing. I do not know why people just downvote such questions. What is the matter. No answer yet but already blaming me. That's quite... human.
Edit:
Using "tokens=*" will properly read the last line, but only the last line. Improofed, but not a lot...

Comment: As an aside: I would recommend switching to PowerShell, which has native, object-oriented support for CSV files. Your life will be _much_ easier than trying to use the `cmd` `for` command.

Comment: Is that `)` you have on the line `set line=%%A )` present in your code? That would break things.

Comment: closing parentheses issue already mentioned

Comment: @HeartOfGermany Read all points of my first comment for the explanation of why you are only getting the last line. The tokens factor is not the issue, that's an additional piece of information you ought to know regarding for loop limitations, and the doublequoting of variables is again additional information which is widely accepted as appropriate syntax for ensuring safe assignment of input to variables.

Comment: As for the reason behind the downvote, mine was placed as your issue is caused by typo's / syntax errors, A type of question that is considered off topic as 1) the issue is specific to your own script and unlikely to be of benefit to others and 2) you should have made your own debugging efforts prior to asking the question.

Comment: Now that is strange. I do not know, why the ")" is there... After removing it it printed 3 times "=\Users\Ultron\test\test2.csv" and nothing was inside the file... What piece of garbage code did I find here? I copied it from an answer which was told to work. Nice.

Comment: @T3RR0R: I fixed all the listed errors and the result is as listed in Edit3 of the question. Still not working. I tried to debug it. This is not the first version of code. I tried for quite some time.

For the powershell: I have no time to learn new synthax now. It is however a plan for the future.

Comment: I suggest updating your current code in the question if you have made the suggested changes.

Comment: When you output a variable to a file and the line in the file reads `Echo is Off` (On if the echo state is on) - that indicates the variable is not defined. The cause in your case is that you are Using Normal `%` Expansion instead of `!` delayed expansion in your for loop

Comment: You have enabled delayed expansion at the outset, then for some inexplicable reason after having defined a variable within a perenthesized block, you have tried to use it within that block without delaying its expansion. For that reason the output is empty, _(`echo ` will just return the current `echo` status)_. **Just change both instances of `%line%` within that parenthesized block, to `!line!`**.

Comment: Yep, already noted that problem. The funny thing is, the first try I had actually used !var! instead of %var%. This was the result of trying around while debugging. Not it finally works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, it did not read and write correct was more than one detail.

Required for the fix:

- I removed the tokens number
- changed the file output. It has to use the !var! synthax (delayedexpansion)
- remove a ")" which I did not see after many tries. How embarassing...
- use a strange synthax like ('type "C:\path with spaces\stuff"'), so the script works with a path with a space - since this is the targeted usecase

The result looks just like:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
cls


del "K:\Users\Ultron\test\te st\test2.csv"
echo CSRV>>"K:\Users\Ultron\test\te st\test2.csv"


for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('type "K:\Users\Ultron\test\te st\test.csv"') do (
set "line=%%A"
set "line=!line: =!"
set "line=!line:    =!"
(echo !line: =!)>>"K:\Users\Ultron\test\te st\test2.csv"
)


notepad "K:\Users\Ultron\test\3.7-12V_inductor_current\te st\test2.csv"
```

This results in the expected .csv:

```
test 
test 
test. 
thisssssatest
```

Comment: note: `echo !line: =! >>file` adds a (probably unwanted) space at the end of each line. Change the syntax to `>>file echo "!line!" or `(echo !line!)>>file`

Comment: or better yet surround the entire for loop in parentheses and move the redirection to the outside of the for loop. `(For /F "OPTIONS" %%X In (Set) Do (commands))>"%~dp0outfile.txt"`

Comment: Correct. I did not fix this, since it is not a problen. But yeah, I was wondering for half a sec., why these where there. Obviously the space is the problem. Thanks for the >>file echo etc. tip. I would usually write it like so: !line: =!>>"K:\Users\ This also works a treat. Sometimes batch is very flexible like this time, at other times it is just insane, how complicated such a super-simplistic scripting language can be. :D

Comment: `!line: =!>>` will give you some headache when the line ends with a single digit (number).

Comment: Stephan, I cannot recreate a situation, that gives me the headache. I tried a line with   "  1" and similar stuff like "this is a test 1". What would be the conditions, to create an error here? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: try with any number but `1`. Btw: you get no error, but you don't get the line into the file. `1>file` is just the full version of `>file`, so `1` (STDOUT) doesn't make a difference here.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done using PowerShell. If you are on a supported Windows machine, PowerShell will be available. Note: this will remove -all- SPACE characters. It will not retain SPACE characters inside delimited fields of a CSV format file. That is the example in the question.

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:/src/t/test2.csv' |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace ' ','' } |
    Out-File -FilePath 'test3.csv' -Encoding utf8
```

If you must run from a cmd.exe console or .bat file script, this can be used.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-Content -Path 'test2.csv' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { $($_ -replace ' ','') } |" ^
        "Out-File -FilePath 'test3.csv' -Encoding utf8"
```

Comment: I will use the .bat version for now. Works peprfectly fine. However your example will be under my examination soon, since I want to dig into PS at some time. So thank you anyway!

Comment: @HeartOfGermany, the second example is a `".bat version."`

Comment: IMO, there is more benefit to writing the entire script using PowerShell rather than calling  PowerShell from a cmd.exe shell script (batch file).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, I agree. But, that is a decision for the OP.